# Why is the Python Requests library getting locked up with some upload requests?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

*No it is not timing out (lets go ahead and get that out of the way).*

I have a multi-threaded Python script for uploading files to OneDrive via the Microsoft Graph API (v1.0), and every so often a request is not returning properly. I have a test folder with 707 files, and usually 2-3 are getting "lost in the ether".

The following is my current code. The try/except block is not catching any exceptions (thus the BaseException). The request is not returning a response/error code.

**IMPORTANT INFO:** The files that are not returning a response **are** getting uploaded. Without any response though, I cannot continue with the thread execution to carry out other tasks.

```
        try:
            response = s.put(
                f'{graph_config["endpoint"]}/sites/{self.sp_site_id}/drive/items/root:/{self.sp_teams_channel}/{folder_path}/{sanitized_filename}:/content', 
                headers={
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + graph_client['access_token'], 
                    'Content-type': 'application/binary'
                },
                data=open(local_file, 'rb').read(),
                timeout=20
            )
        except BaseException as e:
            logging.error(f'BaseException: {str(e)}')
```

I have tried:

- Catching exceptions
- Decreasing max threads
- Uploading chunked encoded files (same issue seems to happen)

I am using:

- Python 3.8.2 (same issue with slightly different version)
- requests==2.24.0
- Ubuntu 20.04 (same issue with 18.04)

Comment: If you are not getting response from the server, maybe the server backend never send the response?

Comment: But then the timeout should kick in, and I would get a 408 error code I could work with.

Comment: In SharePoint/OneDrive for Business, one limitation is that users with appropriate permissions can forcefully check in files that another user has checked out - i think your scenario resembles that.